# Can not post form data in a specific xml format using Django

Tags: python, xml, django

I need one help. I need to save all data into a specific xml format using Django. I am explaining my code below.

> bmr.html:

```
<form method="post" action=" ">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>location name: </label>
    <input name="lname">
    <br>
    <label>Room name: </label>
    <input name="rname">
    <br>
    <label>No of Seats: </label>
    <input type="number" name="seat">
    <br>
    <label>Projector Screen</label>
    <select name="projector">
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Video conference</label>
    <select name="video">
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

> views.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm)
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
def bmr(request):
    root = ET.Element("roomlist")
    ET.SubElement(roomlist, "location name", name="blah").text = "some value1"
    doc = ET.SubElement(root, "location")
    return render(request,'booking/bmr.html',{})
```

Here I need when user will click on `submit` button the post data will save into following `xml` format. I am explaining my format below.

```
<roomlist>
  <location name="Bangalore">
    <room id="1uy92j908u092">
      <roomname> Aquarius </roomname>
      <noseats> 10 </noseats>
      <projectorscreen>yes</projectorscreen>
      <videoconf>yes</videoconf>
    </room>
  </location>
  <location name="Sydney">
    <room id="324det56yuygttrgr">
      <roomname> Capricorn </roomname>
      <noseats> 5 </noseats>
      <projectorscreen>no</projectorscreen>
      <videoconf>yes</videoconf>
    </room>
  </location>
</roomlist>
```

After save into xml file it should also display in that below part of the form in table structure. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

in your template

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'for_the_view' %}">
```

in your views

```
def bmr(request):
    location_name = request.POST.get('lname') //same for other fields
    root = ET.Element("roomlist")
    ET.SubElement(roomlist, "location name", name="blah").text = location_name // sane for other fields
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write("filename.xml")
    return render(request,'booking/bmr.html',{})
```

Comment: I am getting some error here. like `ypeError at /bmr/
cannot serialize None (type NoneType)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/bmr/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
cannot serialize None (type NoneType)
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in _raise_serialization_error, line 1052
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6`

Comment: Actually i am also printing the post value.

Comment: Here how can I again display the data after saving into xml file.

Comment: How to search also the data using the specific id.

Comment: From the begining is it required to create the xml file inside the application folder ?